# Время доступа к стандартным контейнерам

Tags: алгоритм, golang

Привет. Каково время доступа к элементу у slice, array, map в go? O(1)?

Comment: для первых двух - очевидно O(1). Для map нужно смотреть внутрь. Здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677670/what-is-the-big-o-performance-of-maps-in-golang говорят, что в теории, да, O(1), но на практике может быть сильно хуже.